# Castable don't work in XPATH in ORBEON 4.1

Tags: xpath, orbeon

`. castable as xs:date` doesn't work since we updated from ORBEON 3.9 to ORBEON 4.1. in the `xforms:output` tag (in both ref and value attributes).

The associated field is defined using an xsd file as xs:date, field itself has value '' (empty string).

The exception is:

```
org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException: line 1136 of file:///D:/oracle/wls10.3.3/domains/gacr/ (evaluating XPath expression: expression='datumUkonceni castable as xs:date'): null file:///D:/oracle/wls10.3.3/domains/gacr/, line 1136, column -1: null
at org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException.wrapException(ValidationException.java:126)
at org.orbeon.oxf.util.XPath$.handleXPathException(XPath.scala:170)
at org.orbeon.oxf.util.XPathCache$.withEvaluation(XPathCache.scala:516)
at org.orbeon.oxf.util.XPathCache$.evaluateAsString(XPathCache.scala:312)
at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.control.ControlXPathSupport$class.evaluateAsString(ControlXPathSupport.scala:86)
at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.control.XFormsControl.evaluateAsString(XFormsControl.scala:47)
at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.control.controls.XFormsOutputControl.evaluateValue(XFormsOutputControl.scala:75)
at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.control.XFormsValueControl$class.evaluateImpl(XFormsValueControl.scala:80)
at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.control.controls.XFormsOutputControl.evaluateImpl(XFormsOutputControl.scala:58)
at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.control.XFormsControl.evaluate(XFormsControl.scala:204)
at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.control.ControlBindingSupport$class.setBindingContext(ControlBindingSupport.scala:102)
at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.control.XFormsControl.setBindingContext(XFormsControl.scala:47)
at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.control.ControlBindingSupport$class.evaluateBindingAndValues(ControlBindingSupport.scala:59)
at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.control.XFormsControl.evaluateBindingAndValues(XFormsControl.scala:47)
.... stack continued
```

When I use this construction in properties-local.xml `<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.xforms.format.output.date" value="if (. castable as xs:date)
           then format-date(xs:date(.), '[D01].[M01].[Y0001]', xxforms:lang(), (), ()) else ."/>`, then castable is processed as expected ...

Answer (score 0):

With 4.0, use the `xxf` prefix, instead of `xxforms`, in your `properties-local.xml` and this should solve your problem.

In general, XML files in 4.0 have been changed to use shorter prefixes, like `xxf` instead of `xxforms`, `xf` instead of `xforms`, and `xh` instead of `xhtml`. In most cases, this change is backward compatible, as you do the prefix to namespace mapping in your own file, and thus are free to use whatever prefix you like, but there are exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The ref and value attributes of xforms:output tag in ORBEON 3.9 are almost same and xpath expressions in the ref atribute are executed. In the ORBEON 4.1 ref atribute must be reference to element - xpath expression castable as throws exception ..